# Scope in Python standard library code: How is it even possible that these variables exist?

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-asyncio

I took a look at the asyncio package's `__init__.py` file (in Python 3.4.1) and stumbled over the last few lines:

```
"""The asyncio package, tracking PEP 3156."""

import sys

# The selectors module is in the stdlib in Python 3.4 but not in 3.3.
# Do this first, so the other submodules can use "from . import selectors".
# Prefer asyncio/selectors.py over the stdlib one, as ours may be newer.
try:
    from . import selectors
except ImportError:
    import selectors  # Will also be exported.

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    # Similar thing for _overlapped.
    try:
        from . import _overlapped
    except ImportError:
        import _overlapped  # Will also be exported.

# This relies on each of the submodules having an __all__ variable.
from .events import *
from .futures import *
from .locks import *
from .protocols import *
from .queues import *
from .streams import *
from .subprocess import *
from .tasks import *
from .transports import *

if sys.platform == 'win32':  # pragma: no cover
    from .windows_events import *
else:
    from .unix_events import *  # pragma: no cover


__all__ = (events.__all__ +
           futures.__all__ +
           locks.__all__ +
           protocols.__all__ +
           queues.__all__ +
           streams.__all__ +
           subprocess.__all__ +
           tasks.__all__ +
           transports.__all__)
```

How is it possible that they can access `events` and all the other submodules (and their respective `__all__` variables) when those names actually should not even exist, considering the `from … import *` statements above? As far as I can see, the `asyncio/` directory of the standard library is not part of `sys.path` and the submodules themselves don't define a `submodule.__all__` variable, either.

**On a side note**: What I actually wanted to find out by taking a look at the `__init__.py` file was how I can add all my submodules' names automatically to the `__all__` list of my package's `__init__.py` instead of just repeating all those names (as it is done in several other packages of the standard library). My current approach is the following – maybe your answers will reveal how the `asyncio` package manages to pull off that more pythonic-looking trick.

```
from submodule1 import * # does not import __all__
from submodule1 import __all__ as submodule1_all
from submodule2 import *
from submodule2 import __all__ as submodule2_all

__all__ = submodule1_all + submodule2_all
```